# Integral identity in statistical physics

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I found this identity in a statistical physics book, but I can't find a way to demonstrate it and I don't like to take thing as true without knowing why.

The identity is:

$$ |z|=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\log(2\cosh z - 2\cos t)dt $$

Any help? Even just a reference is enough, if you know how this identity is called and/or where to find it.

Comment: I think this appeared here on MSE before, but it's quite hard to find it. Anyway something similar on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h17769p120601

Comment: I tried to look for it, but I'm kinda new to the side and it was hard to find an integral like this. Sadly AoPS seems down now, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be true for complex $z$, because the right side is analytic while the left side is not.  So let's assume $z > 0$ (by symmetry, the result for $z$ and $-z$ will be the same).  We have, after careful attention to branches,

$$ \eqalign{\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \log \left(e^z + e^{-z} - e^{it} - e^{-it}\right)\; dt
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \log\left(e^z \left(1 - e^{it-z}\right) \left(1 - e^{-it-z}\right)\right)\; dt \cr
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \left(z + \log \left(1 - e^{it-z}\right) + \log \left(1 - e^{-it - z}\right)\right) \; dt\cr
&= z + \frac{2}{\pi} \text{Re} \int_0^\pi \log(1 - e^{it-z})\; dt\cr
&= z + \frac{2}{\pi} \text{Im} (\text{dilog}(1-e^{-z}) - \text{dilog}(1+e^{-z}))\cr & = z}$$
since the dilog function is real on $(0,2)$.

Comment: Could you comment on the explicit expression for the integral in the case of complex $z$ and on its dependence on the choice of the $\log $ branch?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to say that $z$ is a real number. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Given a particular branch of $\log$ whose branch cut stays away from the positive reals, the integrand $\log(2\cosh(z)-2\cos(t))$ is analytic for $z$ in some neighbourhood $U$ of the positive reals, and thus the integral will be analytic there.  Since the result is $z$ for positive real $z$, it will still be $z$ for $z \in U$.  But of course this can't be true in $-U$: by symmetry the result is $-z$ there.  $U$ and $-U$ are separated by some set in which $2\cosh(z)-2\cos(t)$ intersects the branch cut.